# For each unique Pandas series value, count an other field

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Data Frame like that :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2], 
                   "colors": ['green', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'green', 'red', 'black']
```

So there are two series with same length but no logical patern between id and colors. Eg id 1 can be blue green, red etc.

That I want to do is to create an other Data Frame with a first row of each **unique** id and next rows with the count of all possible colors.

In my example, I want the result to be :

| id | green | blue | yellow | red | black |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |

I try : but the == doesn't work.

```
print(df.loc[df.id.unique() == df["id"], "colors"].value_counts())
```

Comment: another option, using your idea of `value_counts` : ``df.value_counts().unstack(fill_value = 0)``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `pivot_table`:

```
df.pivot_table(index="id", columns="colors", aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)

# out:
colors  black  blue  green  red  yellow
id                                     
1           0     0      1    1       1
2           1     1      2    0       0
3           0     0      0    0       2
```

Comment: I don't specified but my original Data Frame has not only 2 rows, there are others. So, if I use your solution as is, the result is good but duplicate for each rows. So, to handle, i write : `df[["id", "colors"]].pivot_table(index="id", columns="colors", aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)`